# When we assign a LinkedList (list1) to another (l1), changes made to list1 are not reflected in l1. Why? - C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

Following is the method I wrote for merging two Linked-Lists (`MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2)`). Following is the entire program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedList
{
     public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;
        public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
        {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
     }


    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListNode list1= new ListNode(1, new ListNode(2, new ListNode(4, null)));//Heap -> list1 is a pointer to an object on the heap (list1 pointer itself is on the stack).
            ListNode list2 = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(3, new ListNode(4, null)));//Heap -> list2 is a pointer to an object on the heap (list2 pointer itself is on the stack).
            ListNode list3 = MergeTwoLists(list1,list2);//list3 points to Heap. list3 is also a pointer to an object on the heap. And initially, that object on Heap = null. The list3 pointer (variable), is itself on the stack.
        }

        public static ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) //pass by Reference
        {
            if (list1 == null)
                return list2;
            else if (list2 == null)
                return list1;
            ListNode l3 = new ListNode(0,null),l1=list1,l2=list2;
            ListNode l4 = l3;
            while (list1 != null && list2 != null)//list1 = 1->2->4->null
            {                               //list2 = 1->3->4->null
                if (list1.val <= list2.val)
                {
                    l4.next = list1;
                    list1 = list1.next;//when we are first time in the while loop, list1 now = 2->4->null but l1 (which = list1) still = 1->2->4->null!!
                }
                else
                {
                    l4.next = list2;
                    list2 = list2.next;
                }
                l4 = l4.next;
            }
            l4.next=list1==null?list2:list1;
            return l3.next;
        }
    }
}
```

As shown above (as commented above), when we enter the `while` loop in the method `MergeTwoLists` the first time - `list1 = list1.next`. And `list1` now = `2->4->null` (`list1` was `1->2->4->null` originally). But, `l1 = list1`, so the changes in `list1` should be reflected in `l1`. And `l1` should now also `=` `2->4->null` (initially, both `l1` `=` `list1` `=` `1->2->4->null`).
But, `l1` now still `=` `1->2->4->null` whereas `list1` now `=` `2->4->null`. Why is it so? Am I missing something?

Diagrammatically, what happens in the Heap and Stack (in my opinion):
[image: LinkedList object on HEAP, referenced by pointers (variables) on STACK]

So, why this incompatible behavior that I am seeing? I will be grateful, if you can tell me what is happening in the HEAP and STACK, exactly.

Comment: `list1` in `Main` cannot get modified by the method because it is not passed by `ref`

Comment: TL;DR you are confused about the difference between a reference type and passing by reference.

Comment: @NickBailey, In my opinion, the LinkedList node is passed by reference (since it is a class - reference type). Am I correct? However, my question is about assigning one LinkedList to another. As I put in my problem statement, I assigned l1=list1. And list1=1->2->4->null. So, l1 also became 1->2->4->null. But, when I did list1=list1.next, list1 became 2->4->null. But l1 remained the same - 1->2->4->null. How is this possible - since both list1 and l1 variables are on the stack and point to the same LinkedList object on the heap?

Comment: @VikramSingh `list1 = list1.next` changes the reference stored in `list1` variable and for obvious reasons does not change reference stored in`l1`.

Comment: @UnholySheep, I think you didn't catch the exact problem I am stating. My question is not about passing LinkedList from one method to another. My question is about how the LinkedList assignment is not working in the method - MergeTwoLists.  As I put in my problem statement, I assigned l1=list1. And list1=1->2->4->null. So, l1 also became 1->2->4->null. But, when I did list1=list1.next, list1 became 2->4->null. But l1 remained the same - 1->2->4->null. How is this possible - since both list1 and l1 variables are on the stack and point to the same LinkedList object on the heap?

Comment: You aren't changing the `ListNode` object itself, you are changing what two separate variables are refering to. Both `l1` and `list1` are reference variables, they are refering to objects. Changing what one of them refers to has no effect on what the other refers to

Comment: @GuruStron, thanks for catching the question, that I was actually asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var l1 = list1` in `MergeTwoLists` it makes both variable store on stack reference to the same heap location, but when you do `list1=list1.next` the reference stored in `list1` changes, but the one in `l1` doesn't (cause you have not reassigned it). If you have done something like `list1.next = null` then you will be able to see the change "propagated" to `l1` also since `ListNode` is a reference type.

Comment: This is basically correct, though there are a few key points worth clarifying:

Comment: @NickBailey, can you please mention the few points, that are worth clarifying?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I forgot to press send: value types are not guarenteed yo be stack allocated and reference types are not guarenteed to be heap allocated. The runtime is free to violate those rules  if it detects that it safely can and it would improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging, to see what is exactly happening on the heap and the stack.
For example:

```
1. var a = new Student();
2. var b = a;
```

The above code will result in the following on the heap and stack -
[image]

But, now when we later do:

```
3. a = new Student();
```

The newly added code (at line `3.`) will result in the following, on the heap and stack -
[image: HeapStack2]

This is the same phenomenon that is happening, when we do:

1. `var` `l1 = list1` in `MergeTwoLists`.

Originally, `list1` and `l1` point to the same object on the heap (as shown in line `1.` above). Later when we do `list1 = list1.next`, `list1` variable (on the stack), now points to the `next` `list1 object` on the heap. But, `l1` variable (on the stack), still points to the original `list1 object` on the heap (as shown above, in the `Student() object` example).